# what version of software I need to deploy to get kubernetes 1.19.7

Tags: kubernetes, cri-o

I am trying to setup a kubernetes cluster but apparently the nfs-client-provisioner has issues with the newer versions of kubernetes. Therefore I need to install the latest version of 1.19.

I am creating the kubernetes via kubeadm and I am using crio as the runtime. I am also running the whole thing on ubuntu 20.04. I know that I need to install version 1.19.7 of kubeadm, kubelet and kubectl but whatabout the cri-o?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official documentation from Kubernetes the CRI-O version needs to match your Kubernetes version.

https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#cri-o

So CRI-O 1.19 version should be compatible with the Kubernetes version you want to install.

Comment: for 1.19 version there is only 1.19.1 available while that does not match the kubernetes version.

Comment: There is a difference between version (1.19) and release (1.19.x). You have to match version numbers not release numbers. So in your case CRI-O 1.19.1 is matching  your Kubernetes version as .1 is the latest release of the the matching CRI-O version.